# PHP - Having a placeholder 'echo' so to speak

Tags: php

```
<?
//LUHN ALGORITHM PHP CONVERSION
// CREDIT CARD NUMBER CHECKER BY JACK BELLAMY - JACKBELLAMY.CO.UK

//-----------  RETREIVE THE STRING FROM THE FORM POST -------------//

$var = $_POST['cardnumber'];

//----------- SPLIT THE 16 CHARACTOR STRING INTO INDIVIDUAL CHARACTERS AND ASSIGN TO INDIVIDUAL VARIABLES ---------------//

$n0 = $var[0]; 
$n1 = $var[1];
$n2 = $var[2];
$n3 = $var[3];
$n4 = $var[4];
$n5 = $var[5];
$n6 = $var[6];
$n7 = $var[7];
$n8 = $var[8];
$n9 = $var[9];
$n10 = $var[10];
$n11 = $var[11];
$n12 = $var[12];
$n13 = $var[13];
$n14 = $var[14];
$n15 = $var[15];

// ---------------------CHECKING THE CARDNUMBER FORM POST SUBMITS ALL VALUES PROPERLY
/*

echo $n0;
echo $n1;
echo $n2;
echo $n3;
echo $n4;
echo $n5;
echo $n6;
echo $n7;
echo $n8;
echo $n9;
echo $n10;
echo $n11;
echo $n12;
echo $n13;
echo $n14;
echo $n15; 

*/

//-------ASSIGNING THE NEW VARIABLE VALUES ------------//

$n14_new = ($n14*2);
$n12_new = ($n12*2);
$n10_new = ($n10*2);
$n8_new = ($n8*2);
$n6_new = ($n6*2);
$n4_new = ($n4*2);
$n2_new = ($n2*2);
$n0_new = ($n0*2);

//!-----!------!//

//------------------------TESTING WITH THE NEW VARAIBLE *2

/*
echo $n0_new;
echo $n1;
echo $n2_new;
echo $n3;
echo $n4_new;
echo $n5;
echo $n6_new;
echo $n7;
echo $n8_new;
echo $n9;
echo $n10_new;
echo $n11;
echo $n12_new;
echo $n13;
echo $n14_new;
echo $n15; 
*/

//--------- THE MATHS FOR THE COMPLETE SUM ------------ //

$isitlegit = ($n0_new+$n1+$n2_new+$n3+$n4_new+$n5+$n6_new+$n7+$n8_new+$n9+$n10_new+$n11+$n12_new+$n13+$n14_new+$n15);

//!----MATHS-----!//

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="veri-styles.css"
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-wrapper">
                <div id ="verification-wrapper">
                      <form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                        <div id="input-holder">
                            <input name="cardnumber" type="text" class="input-style" placeholder=""> </input>
                            <button class="button-style">Verify my card</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
<div class="result-class">

<?php
if(isset($isitlegit) && ($isitlegit % 5 == 0)) { // it's good
    $new = "<img src='correct.jpg' />";
} elseif(isset($isitlegit) && ($isitlegit % 5 != 0)) { // it's bad
    $new = "<img src='incorrect.jpg' />";
} elseif(!isset($isitlegit)) { // make sure this is not set
    $new = "<img src='card-number-required.jpg' />";
}

echo $new;

?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I dont want it to display the "correct.jpg"echo or the "incorrect.jpg" echo until the card is checked and validated. How do I display something else there until the card is validated. Or echo something else whilst that input field is empty...Sorry for lack of clarity. Thanks

Comment: Set and echo `$new` before the test to a generic image.

Comment: just like i have with the correct and inccorect images? would it be as simple as that? Jack

Comment: Yes, it is *just* that simple.

Comment: it will end up echoing both though as a null input field is the same as an incorrect card number.....

Comment: but it would be in both as open is the same as incorrect though right. There's no if statement for open. forgive me im new to this.

Comment: edited original. This doesnt work for some reason...

Comment: thanks. ill await your reply

Comment: This has worked brilliantly, excuse the bad syntax, just a quick html setup.

Can i ask what difference the $var made then within the isset().

Thanks for your help, you are a legend.

Comment: The `$var` doesn't get set until you submit the form, so there is no danger of the default pic getting changed until a submission occurs. `$isitlegit` is set when the page initially loads, consequently the 'incorrect' image would show because we said "if isitlegeit is set but fails to calculate show the incorrect image". Now we're checking to see if the form has been acted upon. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes it does. thank you for this, this has not only solved the problem but helped me to fully understand the procedure. Here is the working product :) thanks.

http://testing.jackbellamy.co.uk/card-verification.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three states you need to account for, 'open', 'correct', and 'incorrect' To do that you start with an 'open' state.

```
$new = "<img src='please_enter your card number.jpg' />";
echo $new;
```

You would use that in the first condition of your test -

```
if(isset($var) && ($isitlegit % 5 == 0)) { // it's good
    $new = "<img src='correct.jpg' />";
} elseif(isset($var) && ($isitlegit % 5 != 0)) { // it's bad
    $new = "<img src='incorrect.jpg' />";
} else { // the default view
    $new = "<img src='please_enter your card number.jpg' />";
}

echo $new;
```

Once submitted you can only have one of two states, never to return to the default.

In addition you have left your stylesheet declaration un-closed. Please change it to this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="veri-styles.css" />
```

Comment: Honestly, that couldnt make more sense. It great. But its not working for some reason, it displays the correct state automatically.... Would it help if i gave you my entire html and background php code?.....

Comment: We need to only be working with the relevant code. How much code is it?

Comment: I'd improve the if-statement structure.. The first part can go last as an `else` and the `echo` can be outside of all of those if-statement blocks since at least one of the three conditions will always be true (DRY philosophy.)

Comment: its not too much but i cant see the relevence to be honest it all works fine its just the static state thats getting me....

Comment: See the updated code. Are you sure you're not echoing out something in the HTML code? Is there an image tag?

Comment: again the same problem, here is a working model including the code up to date. http://testing.jackbellamy.co.uk/card-verification.php

Comment: All I can see there is HTML which is not remarkable where this is concerned. Is all of your HTML echoed with PHP? There has got to be something else going on here. Your declaration for your stylesheet is incomplete.

Comment: there was a missing "!" on the first isset() on your code example!

Comment: no i'm wrong. Was using a previous example and doesnt work. My apologies. I just dont understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to achieve this is with AJAX.   Create a div on your page where your initial message is displayed, and then use an AJAX call to submit the form data to a script you'll use to validate it, and within that script, echo either a "Success! Your card has been verified" or a "Unable to validate your card" message.   Then have your AJAX function change the .innerHTML of the div to the responseText element.   You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985299/use-ajax-to-load-webpage-content-into-div) for a good starting point, as well as a note about using the jQuery library to simplify your AJAX implementation.

Edit: In response to another user's downvote, here's some code.

First, let's give your HTML form a call to an AJAX object we'll create.   So change your HTML form code to this:

```
<form onSubmit="return process()">
```

process() is a javaScript function we're going to set up later with the AJAX call.   You already have a div established where you want this data to appear, but we need to give it an id, so change:

```
<div class="result-class">
please enter your card number<img src='correct.jpg' />
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="result-class" id="result">
Please enter your card number.
</div>
```

And also assign an id to your text input:

```
<input name="cardnumber" type="text" class="input-style" placeholder="" id="cardnumber"> </input>
```

Now we'll create the javaScript function.  (This is easier with jQuery, but I wrote it in plain javaScript so you won't need the dependancy if you're not familiar with how to use jQuery.

```
function process(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var cardnumber = document.getElementById("cardnumber").value;
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            result.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","validate.php?cardnumber=" + cardnumber,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();

    return false;
}
```

Now, use whatever php script you were going to use to validate the cc# and save it as a separate script called validate.php   Use $_GET['cardnumber'] variable to fetch the cardnumber data sent from the form, run it through whatever validation process you are using.    Use an if statement to create the responseText element for our AJAX function.  You might have your script set some variable to boolean true or false to check this.   I'll use $validated here.

```
 if($validated){
    echo 'Your card has been verified!';
 } else {
    echo 'Unable to validate your card.';
 }
```

The AJAX function will change the text inside the "result" div to whatever text is echoed by your validate.php script.

This should get you on the right track, barring any syntax errors, I just wrote this all off the cuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(false===$submitted){
echo "Please type your card details here";
} else {

if($isitlegit % 5 == 0)  {

$new = "<img src='correct.jpg' />";

echo $new;

} 
else {
$new = "<img src='incorrect.jpg' />";

echo $new;  

}
}
```

Comment: is this the same as !isset?

Comment: assuming that $islegit is only declared when submitted, yes pretty much.